# Weird Streched Lines

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am a beginner in Blender and working on this chair almost 5 days. As you see, top of chair are streching. I changed UV map several times but it did not work. I am really stuck on this. I tried almost everything.

- Keep corners on subdivision surface.
- mark seams.
- correct face attributes.

please help me to fix this problem. thank you so much.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an edge loop and this will fix the problem:

[image]

If you want to keep the corners round, bevel them:

[image]

Then bevel the edges and mark the seams:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for you quick response. I added but I lost the round shape on corners. Is there a way to keep round corners? I remembered you answered my question before and suggested using bevel on edges instead of subd modifier but then I am curious about this question. Is there no way to use subd modifier using with UV map properly?

Comment: I've edited, I would do that this way